# transfering bitmap from one device to another (Android 4.4+) using HCE

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, hce

I am trying to send image from one device to another using HCE (one device is in card emulation mode and another is in reader mode). I am able to send a string but not an image. On the reader side I always get TAG as a `null`.

Your help will be so appreciated, thanks in advance.

**HCE side (tag side/sender):**

```
   private final static byte[] SELECT_APP = new byte[] { (byte)0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x07, (byte)0xd2, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, };
private final static byte[] SELECT_CC_FILE = new byte[] { (byte)0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0c, (byte)0x02, (byte)0xe1, (byte)0x03, };
private final static byte[] SELECT_NDEF_FILE = new byte[] { (byte)0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0c, (byte)0x02, (byte)0xe1, (byte)0x04, };

private final static byte[] SUCCESS_SW = new byte[] { (byte)0x90, (byte)0x00, };
private final static byte[] FAILURE_SW = new byte[] { (byte)0x6a, (byte)0x82, };

private final static byte[] CC_FILE = new byte[] {
        0x00, 0x0f, // CCLEN
        0x20, // Mapping Version
        0x00, 0x3b, // Maximum R-APDU data size
        0x00, 0x34, // Maximum C-APDU data size
        0x04, 0x06, // Tag & Length
        (byte)0xe1, 0x04, // NDEF File Identifier
        0x00, 0x32, // Maximum NDEF size
        0x00, // NDEF file read access granted
        (byte)0xff, // NDEF File write access denied
};

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mAppSelected = false;
    mCcSelected = false;
    mNdefSelected = false;

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.transferimage1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    NdefRecord picRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("image/jpeg", byteArray);
    NdefMessage ndefMessage  = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { picRecord });

    int nlen = ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength();  // <- this is 164906

    mNdefRecordFile = new byte[nlen + 2];

    mNdefRecordFile[0] = (byte)((nlen & 0xff00) / 256);
    mNdefRecordFile[1] = (byte)(nlen & 0xff);
    System.arraycopy(ndefMessage.toByteArray(), 0, mNdefRecordFile, 2, ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength());
}

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APP, commandApdu)) {
        mAppSelected = true;
        mCcSelected = false;
        mNdefSelected = false;
        return SUCCESS_SW; 
    } else if (mAppSelected && Arrays.equals(SELECT_CC_FILE, commandApdu)) {
        mCcSelected = true;
        mNdefSelected = false;
        return SUCCESS_SW; 
    } else if (mAppSelected && Arrays.equals(SELECT_NDEF_FILE, commandApdu)) {
        mCcSelected = false;
        mNdefSelected = true;
        return SUCCESS_SW; 
    } else if (commandApdu[0] == (byte)0x00 && commandApdu[1] == (byte)0xb0) {
        int offset = (0x00ff & commandApdu[2]) * 256 + (0x00ff & commandApdu[3]);
        int le = 0x00ff & commandApdu[4];
        byte[] responseApdu = new byte[le + SUCCESS_SW.length];

        if (mCcSelected && offset == 0 && le == CC_FILE.length) {
            System.arraycopy(CC_FILE, offset, responseApdu, 0, le);
            System.arraycopy(SUCCESS_SW, 0, responseApdu, le, SUCCESS_SW.length);

            return responseApdu;
        } else if (mNdefSelected) {
            if (offset + le <= mNdefRecordFile.length) {
                System.arraycopy(mNdefRecordFile, offset, responseApdu, 0, le);
                System.arraycopy(SUCCESS_SW, 0, responseApdu, le, SUCCESS_SW.length);

                return responseApdu;
            }
        }
    }

    return FAILURE_SW;
}

@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
    mAppSelected = false;
    mCcSelected = false;
    mNdefSelected = false;
}
```

**Reader mode app (reader side/receiver):**

```
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);  // <- this returns null
    NdefMessage message;

    if (ndef != null) {
        message = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();  // <- cannot get NDEF message as ndef is null
    } else {
        return;
    }
   }
```

Comment: If your are getting TAG as null, you might be getting an Null Pointer Exception, Please post the Log Cat trace.

Comment: You can use just NFC. HCE is for other purposes.

Comment: What code are you using to "send" the image on the HCE side? What code are you using to "receive" the image on the reader side?

Comment: @MichaelRoland i ve updated the code! Any help would be appreciated.Thanx in advance!

Comment: What are the values of the SELECT_*, *_FILE, *_SW fields?

Comment: hi @MichaelRoland i have updated my question the above value i am using

Comment: Could you also post the value that you get for `nlen` in `int nlen = ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength();`?

Comment: @MichaelRoland nlen "int nlen = ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength(); " value is "164906"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your implementation of the emulated Type 4 tag:

1. The capability container defines the maximum size of the NDEF file as 50 bytes (`0x00, 0x32`). However, the acutal length value that you use in the NDEF file (first two bytes) is much larger:

   ```
   int nlen = ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength();         // -> 164906
   mNdefRecordFile[0] = (byte)((nlen & 0xff00) / 256);  // -> 0x84
   mNdefRecordFile[1] = (byte)(nlen & 0xff);            // -> 0x2A
   ```

   Note that the actual length is truncated to `0x842A` (see next)!
2. You use an NDEF message that is larger than the maximum possible NDEF size for a Type 4 tag with mapping version 2.0. The maximum size of an NDEF message that is addressable on a Type 4 tag (mapping version 2.0) is 33022 bytes (`0x80FE`) due to the format of the READ BINARY command. Hence, your NDEF message is not supported on this tag type.
3. You should expect the reader to read only parts of the capability container file (in a similar way as you do for the NDEF file). Currently, you only allow read operations with an offset of 0 and a length of 0x0F).
4. Return proper status words if a READ BINARY command fails (currently you return "file not found").
5. You might want to accept the SELECT (by AID) command even of no Le field is present.